# Ngb not loading when compiling using "system" module

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am using a standard configuration of NgB in my Angular app and **everything works fine** and I have my NgB elements behaving as expected and the app loads and functions correctly. However I needed to change one of the options of the `tsconfig.json` from `"module" : "commonjs"` to `"module" : "system"` and I now get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined
  Evaluating http://localhost:10100/app/app.module.js
  Evaluating http://localhost:10100/app/main.js
  Loading app
    at Object.execute (app.module.ts:31)
    at declarativeExecute (register-loader.js:677)
    at doEvaluate (register-loader.js:609)
    at doEvaluate (register-loader.js:596)
    at ensureEvaluate (register-loader.js:542)
    at register-loader.js:132
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:365)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:125)
    at zone.js:760
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:593)
```

Which is coming from the registration of NgBModule.forRoot in my app.module

The full `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Is that something that is not compatible using the system option or am I missing extra configuration/declarations?

UPDATE: Adding `system.config.js`:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
      '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: Can you post your `systemjs.config.js` or `jspm.config.js` file? Also add the code from `app.module`. You probably just need to add `"format": "register"` in your app package config.

Comment: If I change the module to amd it also works. I don't know if that's expected

Comment: `System.register` modules abide by ES Module semantics, AMD and CommonJS modules, especially as transpiled by TypeScript, do not. Try adding the following to `"packages"`: `{ 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js': { esModule: true } }`. also, what version of SystemJS are you using, there have been recent changes and if your versioning is too liberal you may have updated to 0.20 without noticing or reading the changelog.